# CoreBluetooth detecting the same device multiple timesaver with ScanOptionsAllowDuplicateKey set

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

My code is showing the same Bluetooth devices many times even when the `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey` is set to false. What could be the reasoning behind this triggering multiple calls to the `centralManager didDiscover` delegate and how would I prevent it from happening?

Relevant code:

```swift
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    self.bluetoothStatus = (central.state == .poweredOn)
    if bluetoothStatus {
        centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [
            CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: false
        ])
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this only happen to the MBP? How quickly do you get these repeated discoveries? (seconds? minutes? hours?) I suggest adding a logging statement when didDiscover is called and check the CBPeripheral identifier. Are they the same CBPeripheral? Does any other information change in the advertising packet?

Comment: In addition the Rob's suggestions, please explain (by showing code) how you save the list of discovered devices and filter away duplicates.